# retrieving value from codeigniter database array

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter

i am using

```
$sql= "select *  from tablename where id=1";
$query= $this->db->query($sql);
$row = $query->result_array();
```

in model of codeigniter.My table consists of a field name 'ID'.how to retrive
ID from $row.

```
$id = $row['ID'];
```

which shows

```
<p>Message:  Undefined index: DOCUMENT_ID</p>
```

how to solve this

Comment: Your question is wrong. The message refers to the index 'DOCUMENT_ID' but you are trying to access 'ID' so this cannot be the message from the above code. You have figured it out below - the  $row array is multidimensional as it could have many rows within it

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer
$Id = $row[0]['ID'];

Answer (score 0):

I hope this might help you

```
$sql= "select *  from tablename where id=1";
$query= $this->db->query($sql);
foreach($query->result() as $values){
echo $values->id;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the id is a unique key in your database, as it seems, you should do this:

```
$sql= "select *  from tablename where id=1";
$row = $this->db->query($sql)->row();
```

It fetches the first row of the result. As id is unique, you only want to fetch one row too.

To get id, simply do:

```
$id = $row['ID'];
```

Just an optimized way as compared to the solution you have found.

Answer (score 0):

If you get the row as

```
$row = $this->db->query($sql)->row();
$id = $row->id;
```

you get the first row as an object and should access it as $row->id. You can also use

```
$row = $this->db->query($sql)->row_array();
$id = $row['id'];
```